# How to add plaintext version to Laravel email without using markdown

Tags: php, laravel, email, html-email, plaintext

I have some html emails that may be a bit too custom for a markdown, but I want to add the plain text versions to them. I know markdown emails do both, but can I manually add a plain text version to a mailable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#writing-mailables):

> If you would like to define a plain-text version of your email, you
>   may use the `text` method. Like the `view` method, the `text` method accepts
>   a template name which will be used to render the contents of the
>   email. You are free to define both a HTML and plain-text version of
>   your message:

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.orders.shipped')
                ->text('emails.orders.shipped_plain');
}
```